# For loop through groups after pandas groupby on a dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following pandas Dataframe and create a groupby object:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Colors': ['blue', 'blue', 'orange',
                              'purple', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue'], 
                   'Price': ['500', '500', '200', '300', '765', '1100', '762', 
                              '650'],
                   'Style': ['farm', 'contemporary', 'modern', 'MDM', 
                             'contemporary', 'farm', 'contemporary'],
                   'Location': ['far', 'near', 'far', 'far', 'near', 'far', 'far', 
                                'near']})

grouped_df = df.groupby(['Colors', 'Price', 'Style', 'Location'])

Groups in grouped_df are: 

grouped_df = 

Colors   Price   Style         Location
blue     500     contemporary  near
                 farm          far
         650     contemporary  near
orange   1100    contemporary  far
         250     modern        far
purple   762     farm          far
         765     MDM           near
```

I can iterate over groups by doing:

```
for name, group in grouped_df:
    ..........
```

but how can I do a nested for-loop over all pairs of groups to do an operation on each unique pair of groups? To be explicit, it would be something sort of like use group 1 and iterate over all unique pairs with the other groups, move to group 2 and do the same thing and repeat. Specifically, each operation would end up being a pd.merge() operation on pairs of groups. Is this possible?

Or could it be achieved using `reindex` by `MultiIndex` or something else?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you don't want to repeat the same group pair regardless of the order. In that case, you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
import itertools as it

grouped_df = df.groupby(['Colors', 'Price', 'Style', 'Location'])

for (name1, group1), (name2, group2) in it.combinations(grouped_df, 2):
    # (...)
```